# Why do you use this form for solving linear ODE instead of the other?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My known Method of solving the homogenous part of a linear ODE is given by separating the variables.
E.g:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
y'=4y &\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=4y\\
&\implies \int\frac{1}{4y}dy =\int1dx\\
&\implies \frac{1}{4}\ln|y| =x+c, ~~c\in\mathbb{R}\\
&\implies y =e^{4x+C}, ~~C\in\mathbb{R},~~C=4c
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Why is the method for solving the homogenous part mostly given per definition by using \begin{equation*}y=Ce^{4x},~ C\in\mathbb{R}\end{equation*}
instead? And how could you use the first method for $y_h$ ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your last step isn't correct, it should be $y=\pm e^C e^{4x}$, and also in your second step (where you divide by $y$) you are missing the constant solution $y=0$. Both of these cases are contained in the single formula $y=D e^{4x}$ (which is more easily derived using an integrating factor instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$y=e^{4x+C}=e^Ce^{4x}=\tilde{C}e^{4x}$$

so both forms are equivalent.

Personally, I (and most people, I believe) will find that $Ce^{4x}$ is clearer and cleaner.

Comment: oh god, i didnt think about that for whatever reason. Thanks